# Firestore query by array names

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have data in Firestore as (Collection) Movies -> (Document) MovieId -> (Array).

Each movie document can have many arrays which are named in a date format MM-DD-YYYY. My question is, is there any way to query these arrays by their name? Considering the name is current date.

For example if I want to run a cloud function that gives me all the today's date array from all the movies?

Something like below...

```
var moviesRef = db.collection('movies');
var query = moviesRef.where("01-16-2019", "==", "01-16-2019");
```

The *01-16-2019* is my array name.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this the way your data is structured.  Array type fields can only be queried by their entire contents for equality (whole list to whole list comparison), or for a single element in the array by its exact value using [array-contains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership).

You can't query a document based on the mere existence of a field either.

If you want to query these documents by some date, you will need to add those dates as the members of an array or a fields of an object whose values map to something like 'true'.

Comment: Ohh, it means either I need to change my data structure or need to loop through each and every movie and check whether array with today's date name exists or not :-(

Comment: Either change your data, or duplicate data.  Data duplication is common in nosql type databases in order to help satisfy specific kinds of queries.

Comment: Changing data is a better option instead of scanning each and every movie and check each and every array name with today's date is not a good Idea.

I will move the date to the collection and movie id will be the children of the collection with other values. It will look like below.

var dateRef = db.collection('01-16-2019');
var docs = dateRef.getDocuments();

Thanks for you time and help @Doug Stevenson